# Change active class onClick on different page upon clicking links in the index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my index, I have these links

```
<li class="index1"><a href="page2.html"> Link1 in index </a></li>
<li class="index1"><a href="page2.html"> Link2 in index </a></li>
<li class="index1"><a href="page2.html"> Link3 in index </a></li>
```

**I would want that when I click Link 2, the hidden div#2 on page2.html to be displayed, and default displayed div#1 to be hidden. My codes on page2.html is**

```
<li class="page2 active" target="1"> Link1 on page 2 </li>
<li class="page2" target="2"> Link2 on page 2</li>
<li class="page3" target="3"> Link3 on page 2</li>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
<p> Text here </p>

<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
<p> Text here </p>

<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">
<p> Text here </p>
```

So far, clicking on links in page 2 changes the active li, displays the corresponding div and hides other divs.

Here is my jQuery code

```
jQuery('.page2').click(function(){
  jQuery('.page2').removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});

jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('.page2').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

**If possible, I would like what happens in .page2 click function to be similar that of when you click .index1 from index.html ***

Thanks so much!!

Comment: You have no attr `target` on the other 2 `li`'s

Comment: woops sorry! was trying to make my codes easier to read, forgot about it. thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT*

Because page2.html is a completely separate page from the index page, you'll have to do one of two things to modify the elements.

1) Upon clicking the index on the first page you could add a parameter to the query string.

```
<li><a href="page2.html?index=1"> Link1 in index </a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html?index=2"> Link2 in index </a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html?index=3"> Link3 in index </a></li>
```

upon clicking it would then take you to page2 with the index parameter in the URL, on load of page 2 you can read the value in the index parameter and then hide/show your HTML elements based on the number.

For example:

you could add this jquery to page2.html

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   var index = getParameterByName('index')
   $('ul > li').not('#target' + index).hide()
   $('div').not('#div' + index).hide()
   $('#div'+ index).show();
   $('#target' + index).addClass('active');

});


function getParameterByName(name) {
    url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

2) You could generally do the same thing above, but instead of adding a parameter to the query string just create a cookie upon clicking one of the list items on the index page, and then on page 2 read the contents of the cooking instead of the query string

Comment: Is page2 embedded within the index page or are they completely separate? 

If they are separate you would need to approach it differently, for example you may need to update the query string to include the index of the link you clicked on page 1 and then on page 2 read the query string and then hide/show the elements based on the number you added to the query string from clicking the index on page 1

Comment: completely separate, let me edit my code, sorry. my head hurts trying to get this to work.

^ i can understand the logic on how to get it to work but i don't understand much about the jQuery language to put it into a code

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It'll take me time to understand the code, so I'll copy it in the meantime to test it out. I feel like it's getting there. Clicking on link2 from the index doesn't hide the default displayed div1, and doesn't make the link2 in page2.html active. It displays the text on div2 though! It's close. Thank you. :)

Comment: Its not setting link2 on page2,html as active because, you need to add an id tag to each of the list items like this. 

<li class="page2 active" id="target1"> Link1 on page 2 </li>

Comment: Oh thank youu! I thought it worked the same as target="1", just noticed the "#" in the code. The last problem would be clicking on link2 on index doesn't hide the div1 (already displayed on default) and the <li class="page2 active"> is set on link 1 and link 2 in page2. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: see updated post, you'll have to mess with it a bit to get it to work exactly how you want it but I think the above should get you pretty darn close

Comment: Finally, I got it to work!!! Thank you so much DAmbrozic! :) I understand it a little bit so I was able to tweak what it does, but still unfamiliar with the javascript language. Thank you! I appreciate your help! :D